# Time and space complexity of divide and conquer k-way-merge algorithm

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting, divide-and-conquer

Given that A is an array of k arrays.
Each inner array is sorted and contains m elements.

Given this algorithm for merging K-sorted arrays held in A:

```
// A is array of sorted arrays  
K-arrays-merge(A)   
1.  if A.length == 1
2.      return first element of A
3.  half = length[A] / 2
4.  firstHalfArray = new array[half][m];
5.  secondHalfArray = new array[half][m];
6.  for (i = 0; i < half; i++)
7.      do firstHalfArray[i] = A[i];
8.  for (i = half; i < length[A]; i++)
9.      do secondHalfArray[i] = A[i];
10. secondHalfArray = Copy second half arrays from A
11. a = K-arrays-merge(firstHalfArray)
12. b = K-arrays-merge(secondHalfArray)
13. return merge(a,b) // This is a merge between two sorted arrays with time complexity of O(n)
```

Why is the time comelexity of this algorithm is O(m*klogk)?

My first thought is that the recursive method runs logk times, in each round copying the arrays is O(m * k) and the merge-sort is O(m i log (m i)) where `1 <= i <= logk`

When looking at the divide and conquer steps:

1. Divide - calculating the middle point is O(1), copying the arrays is O(mk)
2. Conquer - 2T(k/2) - The recursive calls.
3. Merge - merge sort with complexity of O(m i log (m i)) where `1 <= i <= logk`.

I do not know how to calculate the time complexity from this. Also what would be the space complexity for this algorithm?

Comment: The question title is for a k-way merge, not for a k-way merge sort. A divide and conquer approach would imply repeated 2-way (or some number less than k) merges until a single merged run is produced, as opposed to doing a single k-way merge. The largest space requirement occurs on the final merge to produce a single sorted run, see if you can figure out the requirements for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we suupose `n = mk`, time complexity would be `T(k) = 2T(k/2) + n + n`.
`n` for array copy, `n` for merging and `2T(k/2)` for recursive call. Hence, time complexity of the algorithm is `O(nlog k) = O(mk log(k))`.

As each time all values of the array copied and stored in the stack, and the depth of stack is `O(log k)`, space complexity would be `O(n log k) = O(mk log k)`.

Comment: So in order to achieve a solution with `mk log k` one must use a min heap? Or is there also a way that is close to this solution with that time complexity?

Comment: I made a mistake on my part. The arrays are all sorted,  so the merging at the last line is O(n). How does that effect the answer?

Comment: can m= O(log k) be said? If so, why? If not, how to find a solution of O(mk log k)?

Comment: @S.Peter The answer is updated. I have a miscomputation in `n/2`. Indeed, we have `2T(k/2)` instead of `2T(n/2)`.